# Python Kivy Raspberrypi Error GPIO Channel

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, kivy, gpio

Im create class for add widgets rectangle in many different positions my layout.
Im runing return error GPIO most setup(), im configure port in line 11, whats problem in my code ?

```
>  Traceback (most recent call last):    File "plantadeira.py", line 50,
> in <module>
>      MainApp().run()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
>      runTouchApp()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in
> runTouchApp
>      EventLoop.window.mainloop()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py",
> line 90, in mainloop
>      self._mainloop()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_egl_rpi.py",
> line 85, in _mainloop
>      EventLoop.idle()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 327, in
> idle
>      Clock.tick()    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/clock.py", line 581, in
> tick
>      self._process_events()    File "kivy/_clock.pyx", line 368, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-NKJIwl-build/kivy/_clock.c:7219)    File "kivy/_clock.pyx",
> line 398, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-NKJIwl-build/kivy/_clock.c:7102)    File "kivy/_clock.pyx",
> line 396, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase._process_events
> (/tmp/pip-NKJIwl-build/kivy/_clock.c:7032)    File "kivy/_clock.pyx",
> line 168, in kivy._clock.ClockEvent.tick
> (/tmp/pip-NKJIwl-build/kivy/_clock.c:3109)    File "plantadeira.py",
> line 26, in update
>      if  self.read_Sensor(pin) == False:    File "plantadeira.py", line 36, in read_Sensor
>      sensor = GPIO.wait_for_edge(int(pin), GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)  RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel as an input first
```

This is my code python:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
pin_1 = 17

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass            

class bar(Widget):

    r = NumericProperty(1)
    def __init__(self, pin, p1, p2, s1, s2, **kwargs):
        super(bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)        
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)

    def update(self, pin):
        if  self.read_Sensor(pin) == False:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 0, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(p1,p2), size=(s1,s2))
        else:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 1, 1, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(p1,p2), size=(s1,s2))            

    def read_Sensor(self, pin):
        sensor = GPIO.wait_for_edge(int(pin), GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)
        if sensor is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.mainlayout = Widget()
        bar1 = bar(pin_1, 1, 10, 60, 100)
        self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar1)
        return self.mainlayout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is when you call:
  `GPIO.wait_for_edge(int(pin), GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)`
you can not use `int(pin)` but rather `pin_1` which you defined before the class.
So you could call it like this instead:
 `GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin_1, GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)`

If you want to use `pin` in your code, you must define it as `self.pin = pin` in the initiation of the object. (**init**). And then refer to it as `self.pin` anywhere in the class. You dont need to pass it as parameter in your update -> read_Sensor method in this case. Unless you got several pins, but then you need to pass a number to the read_Sensor method. You dont do that in your code. You dont pass any number to the update method.
pin in your case becomes Clocks `dt`, (delta time) as from the docs https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.clock.html

If you look at the error you see that `int(pin)` was never set to be a input. As mentioned before `int(pin)` is the Clocks delta time, so it will never be the same.
`RuntimeError: You must setup() the GPIO channel as an input first`

And just to show how you can rewrite this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Color, Rectangle
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
pin_1 = 17

class MainLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass 

class bar(Widget):

    r = NumericProperty(1)
    def __init__(self, pin, p1, p2, s1, s2, **kwargs):
        super(bar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.5)
        self.pin = pin

    def update(self, dt):
        if  self.read_Sensor() == False:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 0, 0, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(p1,p2), size=(s1,s2))
        else:
            with self.canvas:
                Color(self.r, 1, 1, 1)
                Rectangle(pos=(p1,p2), size=(s1,s2))            

    def read_Sensor(self, pin=self.pin):  # you dont need to pass anything to this method. It will default to self.pin. But if you need it for other sensors, you can pass an integer.                                                                                            
        sensor = GPIO.wait_for_edge(pin, GPIO.RISING, timeout=1000)                                                                   
        if sensor is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.mainlayout = Widget()
        bar1 = bar(pin_1, 1, 10, 60, 100)
        self.mainlayout.add_widget(bar1)
        return self.mainlayout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: @VictorSued great. No problem.